# How to create a directory per each user with only access to the user and domain administrator?

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

For my company, I would like to create a single directory for each user in a server. Each directory must be personal, and I would like to create a desktop link to that directory. For example, in my server SERVER01 I need a simple structure like

```
users\johnsmith

users\robertgreen

users\johndoe
```

Each directory must have a limit of 5 gigabytes and must be accessible only to the single user and to the domain administrator. How to do in Active Directory? With a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into using Folder Redirection. This way, your users will be able to use their normal folders like Documents and Desktop, and it will be transparently mapped to the folder on the server whenever they log in. It's a part of the Group Policy settings in Active Directory.

Answer (score 4):

Make a top level folder called `users` share it with read access to Authenticated Users. Make sure you set the NTFS ACL to apply to "this folder only". Then create a subfolder for each user and give users access to *only* their own folders via NTFS ACLs.

You'll use the File System Resource Manager to set a 5GB quota for everyone.

To map the folders, you can use a logon script or group policy - it depends on your environment and what you're more comfortable supporting.